# How to move commerce kickstart database to other domain

Tags: commerce

How to move commerce kickstart database to another domain.

When i copied my files and database tables and edited the settings.php the site just redirects to install.php

Comment: Welcome to Drupal answers. This question is a little vague. Please edit it and add more detail so we can have a better idea where you are expeiencing difficulty. In particular, let us know exactly what you have already tried to correct the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is showing the install.php file because it doesn't recognize your settings.php file - you need to check that this is in the correct sites folder (ex. 'default') and has read permissions for your web user.